# How to access network shared folders in Android

Tags: android, samba, smb

I'm trying to build an application where I want to perform file operations on Shared Drives.
I can share a folder over network in Windows or Linux and then access it in another Windows machine (using Map Network Drive) and in Linux using 'mount'. The file operations then can be done in the same way as for local files and folders i.e. using calls such as CreateFileW, ReadFile etc in Windows and open() , read() etc in Linux. How can this be done in Android ?

I tried one library called JCIFS-NG. While this seemed to be a potential solution, the documentation is not clear at all and I am not sure if this is that way to access network shared folders

Comment: Yes there is jcifs and smbj and all give troubles.

Comment: What kind of troubles ?